# Fixed width of collapse panel in C#, winform?

Tags: c#, winforms

In winform application, i am using multiple collapse panels and each one contains dynamic controls added.

But the problem is, the width of the collapse panels changes dymanically (width reduces on collapsed mode and increases while expanded) but i want fixed width on both mode.

Even i handled collapsablePanel1_PanelStateChanged event and set constant width, but no use.

```
    private void collapsablePanel1_PanelStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      this.collapsablePanel1.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowOnly;
      this.Width = collapsablePanel1.Width;
    }
```

How do i get fixed width collapse panels during expaned/collapes state?

Comment: maybe you should work with onResize Event

Comment: can you specify what kind of control it is? Because this is not standard control.